# Using email username to extract related person

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access that extracts data from a separate customer database. The table has the following fields:

Group No., Group Name, Group Contact, Email

I need to pull the Group Contact and Email for each group to create a mailing list. Some groups have multiple associated emails, but only one matches the Group Contact for the group. For example:

```
`Company ABC   Kermit Frog   miss.piggy@companyabc.com`
`Company ABC   Kermit Frog   fonzo.bear@companyabc.com`
`Company ABC   Kermit Frog   kermit.frog@companyabc.com`
```

I am new to SQL. Is there a way to match the name in the email address that matches the Group Contact name to pull the correct record?

Comment: I don't see how anything "matches" in these rows.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the question, you want the email that contains the the contact -- if any.  This can be a bit tricky, because you don't want to miss any groups.  Here is one method:

```
select g.*
from groups as g
where g.email = (select top (1) g2.email
                 from gropus as g2
                 where g2.groupname = g.groupname
                 order by iif(instr(lower(g2.email), lower(g2.contact)) > 0, instr(lower(g2.email), lower(g2.contact)), 1000)
                );
```